# Laravel file upload not parsed with "multipart/form-data"

Tags: php, laravel, forms, file-upload

I am trying a file upload which I've used before, but seems not to be working now

```
<form action="{{ route('media.upload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="title">
<input type="file" name="file">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
Route::get('upload', function () {
    return view('upload');
})->name('upload');
```

api.php

```
Route::post('upload', 'UploadController@upload')->name('media.upload');
```

Controller Function

```
public function upload (Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

this is the error I'm getting, this is the only readable line

```
"------WebKitFormBoundaryZIiC073OTmdxtEqAContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name" => b""_token"\r\n\r\nTZFHuu4liPLE6Esz2avGRlqLv9K8v1uhKgI7dWw8\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZIiC073OTmdxtEqA\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data
```

I can't use application/x-www-form-urlencode the file is not uploaded

Comment: Are you using ajax request to upload a file ?

Comment: Is that actually an error? What does `dd($request->file('file'));` show? I'm pretty sure that `$request->input()` (and by extension `$request->all()`) treat image uploads differently from `$request->file()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not using Ajax, I'm testing with the laravel blade template, the target is API that's why I'm using the API route

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, thanks to @dgraham answer https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/505#issuecomment-293064470

The header plug-in I'm using had Content-type, I unset all headers except for Authorization and it worked.

Answer (score -5):

What is ur output?

```
<?php
   
                if($request-> hasFile('file')){ 
                $reques->file('file');) ;
                }else {
                return   'file there are not' ;  
                } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Could you add any explanation? Could you mark code as code?